# Conditional density of bivariate normal and normal

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

> Let $Z=X+Y$ where $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ are independents. What is the
>   conditional density of X given Z, $f_{X|Z}(x|z)$?

I already found that $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2(x-z)^2]}$ and $Z \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2+1)$

$$f_{X|Z}(x|z)=\frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2(x-z)^2]}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(\sigma^2+1)}(z-u)^2}}$$
$$f_{X|Z}(x|z)=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2(x-z)^2]+\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2+1)}(z-\mu)^2}$$
After some simplifications I get
$$f_{X|Z}(x|z)=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{1}{2\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}[-(\sigma^2+1)(x^2-2\mu x+\sigma^2(x^2-2zx)-2\sigma^2\mu z]}$$

from here I'm stuck,Is there any easier way to find the conditional?

Comment: @rightskewed But there may be some simplification to get a known distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X$ and $Z =X+Y$ enjoy a *bivariate* normal density where 
$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $Z \sim (\mu,\sigma^2+1)$, and
$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)=\operatorname{cov}(X+Y,X)
= \operatorname{cov}(X,X) + \operatorname{cov}(Y,X)
= \operatorname{cov}(X,X)+0 = \sigma^2.$$
If you are allowed to apply the well-known result that
the conditional density of $X$ given $Z = z$
is a *normal* density with mean 
$$\mu_X + \left.\left. 
\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)}{\operatorname{var}(Z)}\right(z-\mu_Z\right)
= \mu+\left.\left.\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}\right(z-\mu
\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}z +\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2+1}\tag{1}$$
and variance
$$\operatorname{var}(X)\left(1-\frac{(\operatorname{cov}(X,Z))^2}{\operatorname{var}(X)\operatorname{var}(Z)}\right)
= \sigma^2\left(1-\frac{\sigma^4}{\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}\right)= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}\tag{2}$$
then you can just write down the density. Just be careful with
the algebra; it is not hard, just tediously lengthy.

If you are not allowed to use this result, you can proceed as
you described in your question and just try to massage the
result into the final form that you now know it must have.
I note, for example, that the multiplicative factor is
correct in your "final answer" since
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}}}$$
is consistent with the variance given in $(2)$, but I am less
sanguine about the multiplicative factor
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}$ in the exponent: unless
something comes out after simplifying the rest of the exponent that
modifies the multiplicative factor,
the factor should be $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma^2+1}{2\sigma^2}$
to be consistent with $(2)$.

Comment: In (1) is $+$ and not $-$ right?

Comment: And you did in (1) $\rho^2$ just for disappear with root right?

Comment: Yes, in (1) it is a + sign, and I have  no idea what your other comment means.